# Why pthread_condition variable getting hanged?

Tags: c++, pthreads, condition-variable

I just started learning pthread condition variable. But below code is not working as expected.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int count=0;


void *inc_func(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int c;

    while(1)
    {
        cin>>c;
        if(c==8){ 
            pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);break;}
    }

    cout<<"inc count reached 8"<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}

void *watch(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(1){
        pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv,&mutex);
        break;
    }
    cout<<"This executed"<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t id[26];
    pthread_create(&id[0],NULL,inc_func,NULL);
    pthread_create(&id[1],NULL,watch,NULL);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        pthread_join(id[i],NULL);
    }

}
```

when the input is 8 this code gets hanged at "inc count reached 8? I am not able to understand. 
 Where is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing here is that `pthread_cond_signal` will unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on that condition variable (meaning which are currently blocked on a call to `pthread_cond_wait` on that same condition variable). If at the moment when one thread calls `pthread_cond_signal` there is no other thread waiting on that condition then basically nothing happens.

Keeping this in mind, the flow of your program is something like this:

- create and start first thread;
- first thread calls `inc_func()`, which locks the mutex before anything else;
- `inc_func()` keeps waiting for the number 8 to be entered, keeping the mutex locked all this time;
- sometime during this, but most times probably after the `inc_func` managed to lock the mutex, the second thread is created;
- the second thread also tries to lock the mutex right at the start of the function, and is blocked because the first thread already has it locked;
- at some point, you enter `8` and the condition gets signaled from thread 1; **thread 2 is not waiting on this condition yet, so it remains blocked trying to lock the mutex**;
- the first thread finally releases the mutex, so thread 2 locks it and then blocks on `pthread_cond_wait`.

At this point, thread 1 has already finished, thread 2 is blocked waiting for the condition to be signaled, and the main thread is waiting for it to finish. There is nobody else to signal that condition, so you have a hang.

For a quick fix that will **probably** work **most of the times**, you could try changing the order in which you start the threads(start the `watch` thread first). But keep in mind and understand why I used bold for **probably** and **most of the times**.
The correct way to fix this would be to rethink your locking strategy: lock the mutexes in the smallest scope possible and keep them locked for the shortest time possible.

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution to this is to make the `watch` thread only wait if the condition it is waiting for has not occured yet.

The condition appears to be `c == 8` (since that is what is signalled), so you will need to make the `c` variable global so that it is shared between the threads, then change the `watch` thread to do:

```
void *watch(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (c != 8) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &mutex);
    }
    cout<<"This executed"<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Now it doesn't matter which thread runs first: your code is correct either way.  This is the right way to use conditional variables: in general, the waiter should do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

while (!condition)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

/* ... */
```

and the signaller should do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

/* ... something that potentially makes condition true ... */

pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap the thread's execution sequence:

```
pthread_create(&id[1],NULL,watch,NULL);
pthread_create(&id[0],NULL,inc_func,NULL);
```

If you run `thread0` as first, `thread1` never gets past mutex lock, so it doesn't start waiting. Than `thread0` ends, and only then `thread1` executes `pthread_cond_wait()`, but there's no thread to do `signal`.

If you start `thread1` first, it gets to the waiting part.